# Send click event on button loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So this is slightly different than all the posts I have found on the subject. I have a button that gets loaded dynamically via Jquery, I save the selector of this button and later on in my code I need to send a click event (Emulate someone clicking on the button) Now normally I would just use `$('#myID').click();` 
and this casts a click. But Since my button is loaded dynamically this does not work. Now I do NOT need to handle the onclick event. I could use

```
$(document).on('click', '#myId',function(e){});
```

for that. I need to actually send the click event. I have tried

```
.click();
.on('click);
.onClick();
.trigger('click');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Triggering an event should work the same whether the element is loaded statically or dynamically. All that matters is that the element is there when you perform the selection.

Comment: Just make sure you trigger the click after the element is created

Comment: Make sure you call `$("#myId")` after the element is created -- don't try to save that in a variable earlier.

Comment: Are you saying that saving the jQuery object (not the selector) does not work? Obviously you need the most recently loaded object (if the button gets somehow refreshed/reloaded the saved object is no longer valid) but if you have it, the trigger should work. Also the on function cannot be used to trigger the event.

Comment: Please show the actual code. You're probably doing something wrong to get the ID. Maybe you have duplicate IDs? All we can do is guess until we see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: So in response. I am saving the selector in a variable at the beginning of the function as votingButton. then later I get the child of that id (the button) and then I cast the click event. I know I have the right selector because if I console log the buttons html I get the exact text that is on the button (only one button on the page) 
      var myButton= $('#'+votingButton).children();
      myButton.click();
      console.log(myButton.html());

Comment: BTW, you can also log the button element itself.

Comment: BUT what is `myButton` (HTML markup maybe???)? What do you expect triggering click on it to do? And why don't you still provide relevant sample to replicate issue?

Answer (score 0):

By using `setTimeout()` to call the function again and again you are essentially polling the element, untill it actually exists, which is when you fire the click event.

```
// Wait for everything in the document to be loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Make the initial call to the function
    fire_click('#myID');

    // This function tries to find the button, and if it can't
    // find it, it calls itself again in 50 ms.
    function fire_click(selector) {
        elem = jQuery(selector);

        if (elem.length == 0)
            setTimeout(fire_click, 50);
        else
            elem.click();
    }
});
```

A better solution would be to have a callback function that is fired when the button is loaded. This callback function can then fire the click event on the button, since the callback function is only called when the button is actually there. Generally it's a good idea to avoid polling for information when you can, so therefore this would be considered a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also breakout the code that you want to happen when you click on the button into a function if it's simple enough and instead of trying to fire a click event just fire the function the button normally fires.